# Списки инициализации

Tags: c++, c++11

Расскажите в чем принципиальная разница между такими записями

```
class CoinAcceptor
{
...
protected:
    bool m_present {false};
    bool m_emulated = false;
...
};
```

И еще более общий вопрос, когда уместно применять списки инициализации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае эти записи эквиваленты. И да, это не списки, а просто инициализация. Дело в том, что при первом варианте записи внутрь скобок ты можешь вписать только значение, которое предусмотрено типом переменной, которую ты инициализируешь. Т.е. в нее можно вписать только false или true. Если бы это был `int`, то ты не смог бы сделать так:

```
int a {10.0};
```

Так как в скобках не целочисленное значение. Также такую запись можно применять только при инициализации.